# How do i get switch to read multiple characters in c

Tags: c, string, switch-statement

I've been writing a little C code, and I want `switch` to compare multiple characters in a string, but currently I can only get it to check one character.

What i would really like is for it to test if the input was yes, rather than just the first character of the input, so in this case, the y, or the n.

Here is my code:

```
switch (d[0]){
        case 'y':
                printf("Welcome ");
                printf("%s\n", c);
                break;
        case 'n':
                printf("Please Select A New User Name\n");
                memset(&c[0], 0, sizeof(c));
                goto name;
                break;
        case 'N' :
            printf("Please select a new user name\n");
            memset(&c[0], 0, sizeof(c));
            goto name;
            break;
        case '\n':
            printf("that is not a valid command, please try again\n");
            memset(&d[0], 0, sizeof(d));
            goto LOOP;
            break;
        case 'Y':
            printf("Welcome ");
                printf("%s\n", c);
                break;
        default :
            printf("That is not a valid command, please try again\n");
            goto LOOP;
            break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what `switch` is for, it's for taking decisions based on an integer-valued expressions.

You need to use `strcmp()` to compare strings:

```
if(strcmp(d, "y") == 0)
{
  printf("Welcome");
  /* ... */
}
else if(strcmp(d, "n") == 0 || strcmp(d, "N") == 0)
{
  printf("Please select a new user name\n");
  /* ... */
}
```

Note that the above assumes that `d` is a properly-terminated string, i.e. not just a `char`.

Comment: The question was how to compare the string with 'yes', not comparing the first char only.

Answer (score 1):

**ISO 9899 6.8.4.2**

```
The controlling expression of a switch statement shall have integer type.
```

So passing string is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't.

Instead you have to resort to multiple `if` and `else if` statements comparing either individual characters or using `strcmp` to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do it this way?

```
switch (d[0])
{
    case 0x79:
            printf("Welcome ");
            printf("%s\n", c);
            break;
    case 0x6E:
            printf("Please Select A New User Name\n");
            memset(&c[0], 0, sizeof(c));
            goto name;
            break;
    case 0x4E:
            printf("Please select a New user name\n");
            memset(&c[0], 0, sizeof(c));
            goto name;
            break;
    case 0x0A:
            printf("that is not a valid command, please try again\n");
            memset(&d[0], 0, sizeof(d));
            goto LOOP;
            break;
    case 0x59:
            printf("Welcome ");
            printf("%s\n", c);
            break;
    default :
            printf("That is not a valid command, please try again\n");
            goto LOOP;
            break; // Does it really need a break here?????
}
```